# Displaying UIButton Not Working iOS 7 Crashes Device

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, theos, logos

What is wrong with my code?? I am somewhat new to the whole jailbreak development process. If anyone could help me with this. I was trying to do a test of something new that I learned and I was trying to display a UIButton that creates a UIAlertView on the home screen.

```
%hook SBUIController
- (void)finishLaunching
{
UIButton *myButton;
    myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    myButton.frame = CGRectMake(25, 85, 100, 35);
    [myButton setTitle:@"Test" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(myButtonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

SBUIController *ui = MSHookIvar<id>(self, "_uiController");
    [[ui window] addSubview:myButton];
}

%new(v@:)
-(void)myButtonPressed{

UIAlertView *theAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title of Alert"      message:@"Message of Alert" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK",  nil];
[theAlert show];
[theAlert release];

}

%end
```

Comment: Where does the code crash and what is the exception you see?

Answer (score 0):

@selector(myButtonPressed)

simply add : after my button pressed so it become

@selector(myButtonPressed:)